# How do I access the elements in this php array

Tags: php, arrays

Im using a login code snippet from a friend in one of my apps.

He accesses the user logged in by doing:

```
$username_from_cookie = $_COOKIE[$cookiename];
```

How can I get the other elements in that array?

I've tried print_r() and the page returns blank as if php parsing stopped.

Comment: You have an awful lot of rep to not know how to access an array. That's *very* basic stuff.

Comment: Well I used print_r() and it doesn't work.  Plus, rep isn't specific to any language.

Comment: Judging by his user profile @marciokoko has high rep because he appears to be an active and knowledgeable participant in iPhone and Android SO questions. To be fair we all have to delve into problems/languages we are not experts in from time to time.

Comment: @Darragh Indeed that's right, so perhaps we should say that he has an awful lot of rep not to know [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you are bothered by my question, close it.  Otherwise if you don't have something nice to say, just keep it to yourself and let others who are willing to help, do their job.  Thanks @Darragh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/print_r) or [`var_dump()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to inspect the contents of the [`$_COOKIE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) array. Like so:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

or:

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Darragh.  Any idea why print_r() wouldn't work and for some reason stop php parsing?

Comment: Hi @marciokoko. That is very strange... No reason, unless there was a syntax error? Are you getting a WSOD? Or any form of error message?

Comment: If you want to elevate error reporting try adding the following lines right under the first `<?php` opening tag: `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', true);`. It might help pinpoint if there is some sort of fatal error.

Comment: Ok Im getting an undefined variable which is probably related to the No Such file or directory error I get as well. Thanks @Darragh, Im glad SO still has people who despite their rep points are still willing to help!